# How can I disable new follower notifications?

Tags: google-reader

Is there any way I can disable new follower notifications on the Google Reader page? The ones that appear on the top left hand for Google Reader shared items.

Comment: No grease monkeys please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I found. Typing in the javascript

> javascript:antisocial ('true')

in the address bar on google reader, disables the entire social features menu. This disables me viewing people I follow as well. But atleast it's less irritating than seeing those new follower reminders in bright yellow.

Answer (score 2):

I went through each page on the Google reader site, and still finding nothing, contacted Google for support (I actually made my companies adwords rep have someone get in contact with me regarding it).

The response: "There is currently no way do this."

Disappointing. I was really looking forward to doing this, (as were a lot of people I think).

**You can turn off all the followers as mentioned here:** http://www.gtricks.com/google-reader-tricks/turn-off-people-buzz-followers-greader/

By typing the following into the address bar:

```
javascript:antisocial('false')
```

**You can also Disable "buzz" via your google account settings (or Gmail)** which will have the same effect, however you will have to unfollow and delete all your google buzz posts in order to do so. `
[alt text http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/5990/buzze.png](http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/5990/buzze.png)

Comment: In all fairness - I have no idea if the google employee who contacted me actually had anything to do with the product (reader)... But since his answer matched my findings... I'm gonna go with that.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that there currently isn't a way without using GreaseMonkey. I looked through all the options (there aren't that many) and found nothing. If you want to suggest it, have a look at [Product Ideas for Google Reader](http://productideas.appspot.com/#16/e=22493).